# Getting "FATAL EXCEPTION : AsyncTask #2". And I don't know what's causing it

Tags: android, exception, android-asynctask

While trying to call a web service and get the corresponding json object I get a fatal exception. I have absolutely no idea where to look and what errors to correct.

[image: [Screendump of the exception in question](http://i.imgur.com/EZcbW.png)]

*EDIT:*

```
    private class CallServiceTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, JSONObject>
{

    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Object... params) 
    {
        HttpGet req = (HttpGet) params[0];
        String url = (String) params[1];

        return executeRequest(req, url);
    }
}
```

And here's executeRequest method called in doInBackground:

```
    private JSONObject executeRequest(HttpGet request, String url)
{
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    JSONObject jsonObj = null;
    client = getNewHttpClient();

    HttpResponse httpResponse;

    try {
        httpResponse = client.execute(request);

        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {

            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            String response = convertStreamToString(instream);
            try {
                jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
            instream.close();
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e)  {
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonObj;
}
```

Comment: The issue is a class casting issue. Can you post the code in your `doInBackground` method in your asynctask. Thanks

Comment: I think you placed the wrong code. Paste the code where you called the CallServiceTask.excecute(...); from the RestClient.java. To help we need RestClient.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just looking at your LogCat stack trace (in this case) it tells you all you need to know about what this exception is and what has caused it:

> thread exiting with uncaught exception

Tells you that an exception has been thrown which your code does not handle

> An error occurred while executing doInBackground()

This tells you that your doInBackground() function in your Async task has thrown this unhandled exception

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException ...*HttpPost*... (RestClient.java:275)

And that tells you that you have encountered a ClassCastException, resulting from a HttpPost call at line 275 in that source file.

EDIT:

Should have read that stack trace more carefully... as HandlerExploit has posted It's the HttpPost that's throwing that error, where you're expecting a HttpGet... but the following debug method still stands:

If you add an extra catch (ClassCastException e) with an e.getMessage() you'll most likely see a useful error message that describes the problem in more detail.

When in this situation and I find an unexpected exception being thrown like this I tend to add a temporary 'catch all' (catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace() } ) and stick a break point on the e.printStackTrace() so I can see all the details about the exception... might not be the most efficient way of doing it but its a start when you're in the dark!

Comment: It doesn't matter if he wraps it or not, he will still see the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that :

```
HttpGet req = (HttpGet) params[0];
```

Is returning a `HttpPost` instead of a `HttpGet`.

Please post where you are calling `new CallServiceTask().execute();`